# Azure Website and Worker Role html to pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, azure, azure-worker-roles

I have tried several .NET pdf libraries to create a pdf page from a html page.

Well in Azure it's not working for a website because i'm receiving a timeout.

I found on the web people are talking about running the pdf converting as a worker role.

Anyone knows how to configure a worker role to work with the azure website.

I cannot find much info on the web about this. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're conflating things. Azure Websites is a service. Azure worker role is a stateless virtual machine running in a Cloud Service. They are two separate things. Plus, you do not *need* a worker role to generate PDFs (though it's certainly a viable option). You simply need the ability to install your PDF-rendering software, whether that's in Windows or in Linux.

You will not be able to install such software in Azure Websites, but you *can* install software in Azure web/worker roles (via startup scripts) or Virtual Machines (via ssh/rdp). Which you choose, as well as the PDF library you choose, is completely up to you (and out of scope here, since that level of architecture is subjective).

Comment: Thanks alot for your help. This makes sense to me. I understand what i have todo now.

Comment: Please make sure to mark the answer, @Kurt. Welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

EVO has the [solution for converting HTML to PDF in Azure Websites](http://www.evopdf.com/azure-html-to-pdf-converter.aspx). Here is the code snippet for creating PDF from HTML in Azure Websites:

```
protected void convertToPdfButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the server IP and port
    String serverIP = textBoxServerIP.Text;
    uint serverPort = uint.Parse(textBoxServerPort.Text);

    // Create a HTML to PDF converter object with default settings
    HtmlToPdfConverter htmlToPdfConverter = new HtmlToPdfConverter(serverIP, serverPort);

    // Set optional service password
    if (textBoxServicePassword.Text.Length > 0)
        htmlToPdfConverter.ServicePassword = textBoxServicePassword.Text;

    // Set HTML Viewer width in pixels which is the equivalent in converter of the browser window width
    htmlToPdfConverter.HtmlViewerWidth = int.Parse(htmlViewerWidthTextBox.Text);

    // Set HTML viewer height in pixels to convert the top part of a HTML page 
    // Leave it not set to convert the entire HTML
    if (htmlViewerHeightTextBox.Text.Length > 0)
        htmlToPdfConverter.HtmlViewerHeight = int.Parse(htmlViewerHeightTextBox.Text);

    // Set PDF page size which can be a predefined size like A4 or a custom size in points 
    // Leave it not set to have a default A4 PDF page
    htmlToPdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.PdfPageSize = SelectedPdfPageSize();

    // Set PDF page orientation to Portrait or Landscape
    // Leave it not set to have a default Portrait orientation for PDF page
    htmlToPdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.PdfPageOrientation = SelectedPdfPageOrientation();

    // Set the maximum time in seconds to wait for HTML page to be loaded 
    // Leave it not set for a default 60 seconds maximum wait time
    htmlToPdfConverter.NavigationTimeout = int.Parse(navigationTimeoutTextBox.Text);

    // Set an adddional delay in seconds to wait for JavaScript or AJAX calls after page load completed
    // Set this property to 0 if you don't need to wait for such asynchcronous operations to finish
    if (conversionDelayTextBox.Text.Length > 0)
        htmlToPdfConverter.ConversionDelay = int.Parse(conversionDelayTextBox.Text);

    // The buffer to receive the generated PDF document
    byte[] outPdfBuffer = null;

    if (convertUrlRadioButton.Checked)
    {
        string url = urlTextBox.Text;

        // Convert the HTML page given by an URL to a PDF document in a memory buffer
        outPdfBuffer = htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertUrl(url);
    }
    else
    {
        string htmlString = htmlStringTextBox.Text;
        string baseUrl = baseUrlTextBox.Text;

        // Convert a HTML string with a base URL to a PDF document in a memory buffer
        outPdfBuffer = htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertHtml(htmlString, baseUrl);
    }

    // Send the PDF as response to browser

    // Set response content type
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");

    // Instruct the browser to open the PDF file as an attachment or inline
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("{0}; filename=Getting_Started.pdf; size={1}",
        openInlineCheckBox.Checked ? "inline" : "attachment", outPdfBuffer.Length.ToString()));

    // Write the PDF document buffer to HTTP response
    Response.BinaryWrite(outPdfBuffer);

    // End the HTTP response and stop the current page processing
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain to me what is server IP and port number here? And how our code will execute on the server?

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of the Rotativa nuget package. For security policy reasons and OS limitations it can't be used on Azure websites. To address this issue I created a SaaS version on Azure.

It's an API that's really easy to use, just install dedicated nuget package:

```
PM> Install-Package RotativaHQ
```

And create PDF files from Razor Views, as easy as:

```
return new ViewAsPdf(model);
```

No need for anything special in the View/HTML. No need for absolute URLS in images/css/js links. Works on localhost (dev machine) too.

Currently the service has endpoints in 4 Azure regions: US East, US West, EU North, Southeast Asia.

It's fast since it uses a proprietary protocol to send the web page contents to the API for conversion to PDF.

It's reliable because all endpoints are load balanced.

Details on the web site:

https://rotativahq.com